# Verifying Mock method was called inside Task.Run

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

How can I verify that a method was called on a mock when the method itself is called in a delegate passed to `Task.Run`? By time `mock.Verify` is called the Task still hasn't executed.

I have tried `await Task.Delay` just before `mock.Verify` but this seems to leave the test runner hanging.

The reason for using `Task.Run` is to offload the logic to prevent an attacker from being able to differentiate whether the email address exists in the system by the time to execute.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

namespace AsyncTesting
{
    class MyController : Controller
    {
        public IEmailService EmailService { get; set; }

        public MyController(IEmailService emailService)
        {
            EmailService = emailService;
        }

        public ViewResult BeginPasswordReset(string emailAddress)
        {
            BeginPasswordResetAsync(emailAddress);

            return View();
        }

        private Task BeginPasswordResetAsync(string emailAddress)
        {
            return Task.Run(delegate
            {
                EmailService.Send(emailAddress);
            });
        }

    }

    internal interface IEmailService
    {
        void Send(string emailAddress);
    }

    internal class MyControllerTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void BeginPasswordReset_SendsEmail()
        {
            var mockEmailService = new Mock<IEmailService>();
            var controller = new MyController(mockEmailService.Object);
            const string emailAddress = "email@domain.com";

            controller.BeginPasswordReset(emailAddress);

            mockEmailService.Verify(es=>es.Send(emailAddress));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about MSTest but with NUnit you could have an async test method and await the `BeginPasswordResetAsync` method. The Task will have finished after awaiting. Have a look into async tests with MSTest.

Comment: `The reason for using Task.Run...` Sorry, but that's a poor reason to introduce a failure point like this into your app. `Task.Run` is extremely dangerous on ASP.NET; at the very least, use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary, I'll read over your dicussions on the subject http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html

Comment: @RDay: My post on [fire and forget](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) is more directly applicable here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your task you could set a ManualResetEvent (which our test code blocks on using something like:

```
Assert.IsTrue(yourEvent.WaitForOne(TimeSpan.FromSecond(<max time you want to wait>), "the event failed to run");
```

like this:

```
public void BeginPasswordReset_SendsEmail()
{
    const string emailAddress = "email@domain.com";

    ManualResetEvent sendCalled= new ManualResetEvent(false);

    var mockEmailService = new Mock<IEmailService>();
    mockEmailService.Setup(m => m.Send(emailAddress)).Callback(() =>
    {
        sendCalled.Set();
    });

    var controller = new MyController(mockEmailService.Object);

    controller.BeginPasswordReset(emailAddress);

    Assert.IsTrue(sendCalled.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)), "Send was never called");
    mockEmailService.Verify(es => es.Send(emailAddress));
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Some quick research it looks like it is possible with MSTest. e.g.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task BeginPasswordResetAsync();
{
    await BeginPasswordResetAsync("emailAddress");

    mockEmailService.Verify...
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it seemed to hang the test runner. Also the actual async method is private to the controller.