# Unit testing with Moq method invoked inside of Task.Run

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, assert

I am trying to mock a service call inside of a method that I want to test.

The method body looks like this:

```
public string OnActionException(HttpActionContext httpRequest, Exception ex)
{
    var formattedActionException = ActionLevelExceptionManager.GetActionExceptionMessage(httpRequest);

    var mainErrorMessage = $"[{formattedActionException.ErrorId}]{formattedActionException.ErrorMessage}, {ex.Message}";

    this.LogError(mainErrorMessage, ex);

    if (this._configuration.MailSupportOnException)
        Task.Run(async () => await this._mailService.SendEmailForThrownException(this._configuration.SupportEmail, $"{mainErrorMessage} ---> Stack trace: {ex.StackTrace.ToString()}")); 

    return $"(ErrID:{formattedActionException.ErrorId}) {formattedActionException.ErrorMessage} {formattedActionException.KindMessage}";
}
```

What I am trying to mock inside my test is:

**Task.Run(async () => await this._mailService.SendEmailForThrownException(this._configuration.SupportEmail, $"{mainErrorMessage} ---> Stack trace: {ex.StackTrace.ToString()}"));**

The test method looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void We_Send_System_Exception_On_Email_If_Configured_In_Settings()
{
    // arrange
    this._configurationWrapperMock.Setup(cwm => cwm.MailSupportOnException)
        .Returns(true);
    this._mailServiceMock.Setup(msm => msm.SendEmailForThrownException(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(0));

    // act
    var logger = new ApiLogger(this._configurationWrapperMock.Object, this._mailServiceMock.Object);
    logger.OnActionException(
        new HttpActionContext(
            new HttpControllerContext()
            {
                Request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                    RequestUri = new System.Uri("https://www.google.bg/")
                }
            }, 
            new ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor() { }
        ), 
        new System.Exception());

    // assert
    this._mailServiceMock.Verify(
        msm => msm.SendEmailForThrownException(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()), 
        Times.Once);
}
```

The problem is that the method is never invoked, so my assert fails.

EDIT: I could change my question to: How do I need to re-write my method in order to make it testable?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the test to see if code goes through the expected path?

Comment: Task is running, just in another thread so you are unable to verify it.

Comment: @KerriBrown It does go over this line, I debug it but the Moq doesn't detect it was passed. Moq says it was never invoked.

Comment: Because it never invoked on the thread that called the verify.

Comment: @user2128702 don't you get a green squiggly warning in the IDE warning about the task executing on a separate thread?

Comment: @Nkosi Not really.

Comment: @user2128702, Ok well besides that this is a threading issue. Edit the question to match what the actual problem is.

Comment: @user2128702 consider refactoring to make the methods async and also the test. Barring that you can try this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728596/verifying-mock-method-was-called-inside-task-run

Comment: @user2128702 add your solution as a self-answer with relevant code example so that others can potentially benefit from it in the future. Do not include it as an update in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a simple, cut down version of your scenario above and the unit test consistently passes.

```
public interface IService
{
    Task<bool> Do();
}

public class AsyncService : IService
{
    public async Task<bool> Do()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private IService service;

    public MyClass(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Run()
    {
        return await this.service.Do();
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task TestAsyncMethod()
{
    Mock<IService> mockService = new Mock<IService>();
    mockService.Setup(m => m.Do()).Returns(Task.FromResult(false));

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(mockService.Object);
    await myClass.Run();

    mockService.Verify(m => m.Do(), Times.Once);
}
```

It looks like you will need to make OnActionException return a Task<string> and then make the unit test asynchronous also. So rather than using Task.Run(), just return the await this._mailService.SendEmailForThrownException() in the OnActionException method.

Comment: I will accept your answer. I have tried it before and I know it will work. I was just curious if it is possible to make my current situation work.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is a classic situation to apply [Humble Object Pattern](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html).

In this case all you have to do is to extract `Task.Run` into a virtual method, then partial mock the SUT and override this virtual method:

```
public class ApiLogger
{
    ...

    public string OnActionException(Exception ex)
    {
        ...
        if (this._configuration.MailSupportOnException)
            RunInTask(...);
        ...
    }

    public virtual Task RunInTask(Action action)
    {
        return Task.Run(action);
    }
}
```

Then the test will look like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void We_Send_System_Exception_On_Email_If_Configured_In_Settings()
{
    ...

    var logger = new Mock<ApiLogger>(MockBehavior.Default, 
                                     new object[]
                                     {
                                       this._configurationWrapperMock.Object, 
                                       this._mailServiceMock.Object
                                     }).Object;

    logger.OnActionException(...);


    this._mailServiceMock.Verify(
            msm => msm.SendEmailForThrownException(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()), 
            Times.Once);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I came up with was to extract new service metod which is Sync and inside of it I privately call my async method inside of a separate thread using Thead.Run.

```
public void ReportExceptionOnEmail(string recipient, string exceptionBody)
{
    Task.Run(async () => await this.SendEmailForThrownException(recipient, exceptionBody));
}

private async Task SendEmailForThrownException(string recipientEmail, string exceptionBody)
```

So, now I can unit test my **ReportExceptionOnEmail** method with no problem.